# Can't install 2.8

Tags: installation

I have been using 2.8 Alpha.  Today I tried to install the 2.8 release and it comes up with an error "The specified account already exists"  I've tried everything I know to do and no joy.

Comment: As a workaround for when the .msi installer doesn't work: Download the zip archive version (https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-windows64.zip/ or https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-windows32.zip/), extract it and add a shortcut to the blender.exe inside the folder. No installation required.

Comment: Super.  Thanks a bunch